# syntax for calling virtual functions outside of the class?

Tags: c++, class, virtual-functions

what is the syntax for defining virtual functions outside the class body?

```
class random{

public:
   random(int i = 0);
   virtual ~random(){};
   virtual void print() const;
protected:
   int id;      

};
```

is it?

```
virtual void random::print() {


}
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just:

```
struct foo
{
    virtual void bar(void) const;
};

void foo::bar(void) const
{
}
```

`virtual` only goes on the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In your case:

```
void random::print() const {


}
```